# Update existing fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

For example:

```
db.getCollection('user')
  .update(
         {
            "userDetails.username": "ky"
         }, 
         {
            "$set": 
                  {
                     "active": false, 
                     "admin": false, 
                     "phone": "08432808"
                  }
         })
```

In the above code, if the document doesn't have the "active" field, mongodb will insert that field for you. I would like to get some error message in return in such situations, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve something like this using a foreach, filtering what you want to check and then verifying whether the property exists if not throw an exception. Can't say I'm a fan of this, I'd rather have the application logic verify the record exists and have a decision there of whether to update or do another action.

```
db.user.find({"userDetails.username": "ky"}).forEach(function(doc){ 
    if (!doc.hasOwnProperty('active')){
        throw "No active property";
    }
    else{
        db.user.update({ _id: doc._id }, { "$set": { "active": false }})
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks a bit cumbersome, especially when you have a lot of fields to update.

Comment: @qed Yeah I don't like it at all, can you not just build the requirements in to the find? e.g. `db.user.update({"userDetails.username": "ky", active : {$exists : true}}, {"$set": {"active": false}})`. Do you actually need an error?